# How to parameterize multiple kubernetes manifests in terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubectl

I have the following in `main.tf`

```
data "kubectl_path_documents" "yaml-files" {
  pattern = "${path.module}/manifests/*.yaml"
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "yaml-manifests" {
  for_each  = toset(data.kubectl_path_documents.yaml-files.documents)
  yaml_body = each.value
}
```

I would need to parameterize certain fields in the yaml files to be able to deploy different set of resources for dev vs prod. I knew there was a way to do this if it was one yaml. How should this be done for many yaml files

```
├── manifests
│   ├── gdp-configmap.yaml
│   ├── gdp-agent-deamonset.yaml
│   ├── gdp-collector-configmap.yaml
│   ├── gdp-collector-deployment.yaml
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "I knew there was a way to do this if it was one yaml." Please explain how this would be different for you based on the number of manifests. I would think it would not matter, so it would be useful to know why.

Comment: I'd strongly advice to use https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kbst/kustomization/latest/docs/resources/resource and simply use kustomize's mechanics to achieve the parametrization based on environment.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this using a null_resource that executes a sh script with values to be sed'ed.